# XAMPP for Mac: Configure virtual host

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtual-hosts

My problem is configure a virtual host for an web application with php and Xampp. The principal application, named `"AEPAMG.upo.es`" is working, but when I add `"Viafirma-client-php"` as other app and another virtual host, browser say me "Not found". I include some pictures where you can see the configurations:

[image: /etc/hosts configure hosts]

[image: /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf configure localhost's virtual host]

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G8UiX.png
[4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/85eKF.png

Comment: so which virtual host you want to configure in addition?

Comment: http://i65.tinypic.com/2uxwsd4.png
http://i68.tinypic.com/10eg6c5.png
http://i64.tinypic.com/dnemtf.png

More pictures. I can see the host "aelpamg.upo.es" with my application "AE". With the application "Viafirma" is saw with localhost and not with "aelpamg.upo.es/viafirma"

Comment: if you new application is in folder under your already defined vitrual host, you don't need additional entry in your host file, i.e. `aelpang.upo.es/viafilrma` is redundant, remove it. Just put your new code in `viafirma` folder under you host's root.

Comment: And I can't configure as two separated applications? It can be that I use Viafirma app with others applications.

Comment: yes, you can, but you cannot define host with slashes in host file (`host/folder` is wrong there). so if you want, you can create `viafirma.aelpamg.upo.es` for example. if you want `aelpang.upo.es/viafilrma` to work, just place `viafirma` folder INTO your old project, not in xampp root (as is now).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help!! :-D